# Firebase Cloud Messaging Token

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, token

I'm following the tutorial with Firebase Cloud Messaging. The tutor is using token from **Project Settings -> Cloud Messaging**.
This is his screen:
[image]

But I only have sender ID:
[image]

What I missed here? What should I do to get this token or maybe create one?

Comment: From the navigation Projecting settings tab select AppCheck there make sure you enabled SafetyNet option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're following a tutorial that is using the Legacy FCM API.

Just click the **`⁝`** icon to go to Cloud console.
[image]

Then, enable the Cloud Messaging API.
[image]

After this, it will show the server key in the Cloud Messaging tab.

However, I would recommend using the HTTP v1 API as this has the updated server features. You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1). This requires a different setup than the Legacy API but you can follow this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server) on how to set it up.